# Python list print tabulation

Tags: python, list, printing, tabs

I want to print tabulated list, but I can't tabulate first member of list.

```
list = ['data', 'data','data']
print(*list, sep='\n \t')
```

But I get:

```
data  
    data  
    data
```

I would like to get:

```
    data  
    data  
    data
```

How to tabulate first member?

Comment: `print (list[0])` ? I really don't understand your problem, what is your desired output?

Comment: Sorry, I kinda failed to explain properly. Now I edited post

Comment: What does `-----` means?

Comment: I didn't knew how to tabulate lines in this site. - represents just space. Sorry, will look into formatting of posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean this,

```
l = ['data', 'data','data']
s = '\n'.join(['\t'+item for item in l])

print(s)
# Ouput
    data
    data
    data
```

Comment: I'm very new to this site I failed to format my post the way I wanted. Only now I edited the way I want. With a little changes I got what I wanted. Thanks !

Comment: @SoulJam, `----` is `\t` in your case?

Comment: Yes. I Haven't learnt fully how to operate on this site. Sorry, next time I will format properly.

Comment: @SoulJam, don't worry. Every expert was once a beginner.